# webforms ajax file upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <uc1:PageHeaderDisplay id="pageHeaderDisplay1" runat="server"></uc1:PageHeaderDisplay>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="postedFormData" />

        <div style="display: none;" class="uploadxmlcontainer">
            Upload XML: <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUpload" onChange="$('.uploadFile').click();"  /><asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="uploadFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadFile" style="display: none;" />
        </div>
```

I have a fileupload control inside the original asp.net webforms form. What would be the easiest way to implement a non-postback solution? My problem is that when the user, for example, add some table rows using jquery -> uploads a file = the rows dissapear because of the postback.

Can i use a plugin like ajaxforms for asp.net webforms? Or can you make an iframe that posts to the main page? Im looking for a simple solution, if possible :-)

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you can use Qjuery plungin as uploadify (flash upload control) with Ajax
It is simple:

1. Download plugin from http://www.uploadify.com/download/
2. Add to HTML

```
    <div id="fileuploader">
```

1. Set JQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(
        function () {
            $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
                'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                'cancelImg': '/Images/cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Upload Image',
                'script': 'Upload',
                'folder': '/uploads',
                'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                'fileExt': '@imageType',
                'multi': false,
                'auto': true,
                'sizeLimit'   : 204800
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
```

More details: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/